# MachO file format - Value of `fileoff` field in LC_SEGMENT_64 load command

Tags: macos, mach-o, otool

I compiled a simple program such as

```
int main()
{
    return 0; 
}
```

using Clang into an executable and asked `otool` to report the load commands generated by the compiler. The one I'm interested in is `LC_SEGMENT_64`, in particular the one that describes the `__TEXT` segment within the file. The description I get is this:

```
$ otool -lV foo
foo:
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __PAGEZERO
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x0000000100000000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 0
  maxprot ---
 initprot ---
   nsects 0
    flags (none)
Load command 1
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 312
  segname __TEXT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100000000
   vmsize 0x0000000000001000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 4096
  maxprot rwx
 initprot r-x
   nsects 3
    flags (none)
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100000f90
      size 0x000000000000000f
    offset 3984
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
      type S_REGULAR
attributes PURE_INSTRUCTIONS SOME_INSTRUCTIONS
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
```

My question is: why is the `fileoff` field in the second load command set to zero?

Apple's documentation for this field states that

> The file is mapped starting at fileoff to the beginning of the segment in memory, vmaddr.

This, initially, led me to believe that this field, in conjunction with `filesize`, indicated the loader something like this: "Take the contents of the file from `fileoff` to `fileoff + filesize` and this is the sequence of instructions you're gonna ask the processor to run". But my assumption doesn't hold if this value is zero, of course.

I thought that, since the segment has at least one section, the loader will use the value of the respective offset in the section's description to locate the code to run, and hence such value isn't exactly needed --- we can see that, in fact, the first section within this segment has a value for the `offset` field (in this case 3984, which I validated with `otool -s __TEXT __text -j foo` and indeed refers to the offset at which this section is located within the file).

But, if I do the same thing to the object file generated from the same source file (i.e. a file with type `MH_OBJECT` instead of `MH_EXECUTE`), the result I get is this:

```
$ otool -lV foo.o
foo.o:
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 312
  segname
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x0000000000000070
  fileoff 464
 filesize 112
  maxprot rwx
 initprot rwx
   nsects 3
    flags (none)
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000000000000
      size 0x000000000000000f
    offset 464
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
      type S_REGULAR
attributes PURE_INSTRUCTIONS SOME_INSTRUCTIONS
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
```

In this case, the load command does have a value for its `fileoff` field, which is the same as the one for its first section, `__text`.

Comment: "I compiled a simple C program" - so why added C++ tag then? (rhetorical question, don't answer)

Comment: @Olaf Because the same issue arises with a C++ compiler, maybe?

Comment: "**maybe**". C++ is a different language. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. Actually the question is hardly even about C.

Comment: Ok, my goal here is to get an answer to the question. I politely request to end this nonsense.

Comment: Using correct tags is not nonsense, but helps structuring and sorting questions. And note I already **did** tell you the question in my comment was rhetorical. I just thought informing you why I removed the tag was a matter of politeness and helps to avoid this flaw in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

otool makes it hard to realize, but the answer is simple - Observe here:

```
$ jtool -v -l /tmp/a | grep SEG
LC 00: LC_SEGMENT_64          Mem: 0x000000000-0x100000000  File: Not Mapped    ---/--__PAGEZERO
LC 01: LC_SEGMENT_64          Mem: 0x100000000-0x100001000  File: 0x0-0x1000    r-x/rw__TEXT
LC 02: LC_SEGMENT_64          Mem: 0x100001000-0x100002000  File: 0x1000-0x1098 r--/rw__LINKEDIT
```

The __TEXT segment is mapped from the beginning of the file (or slice, if fat ("universal")). That is, with the Mach-O header. This is actually a feature, because the Mach-O then gets parsed by dyld (your friendly loader) for other load commands (notably libraries). The other issue is that __TEXT.__text is often in the very same page , so you'd have to map the whole page anyway.

Comment: You might explain what `jtool` is, since it doesn't come with OS X or Xcode. Also, the `fileoff` is relative to the architecture appropriate slice in a fat binary, not necessarily the start of the file.

Comment: The fileoff is relative to the start of the slice, yes, which is the start of the Mach-O binary (because slices are individual Mach-O). So the explanation is ok, because the header gets loaded either way. And jtool is my own tool. I wrote the book. But last time I gave a link to it the overseers thought it was a promotion and nuked it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this feature, I thought an `LC_SEGMENT_64` load command dealt only with data that was going to be mapped to the process' address space. To my mind, at this point the Mach-O header had already been parsed by the loader and, if any libraries had to be loaded, they were going to be specified by means of `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` load commands. Do you recommend any literature on this subject? (Other than your book, which I just found and intend to take a look at.)

Comment: No; The header A) is parsed also by kernel (for LC_UUID, CODE_SIGNATURE, etc) and B) remains resident. You are correct that other libs are loaded by LC*DYLIB commands. References: Apple's Mach-O Programming topics is nice, but basic. And you can always ask questions here or at the Book's forum.